# How do I change or remove a trade route destination?

Tags: civilization-6

Clicking the trader, there are no options.

Clicking the trader and pressing Delete to kill it has no effect even after clicking on Yes Delete it.

Trade route overview likewise has no options to change or remove trade routes.

Comment: https://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?2027196-How-do-I-cancel-trade-routes this is for civ5 but it could be the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cancel a trade route.
When you set up a trade route, it indicates for how many turns it will run (number near the arrow sign on the trade route info). After the trade route has run its course you will be able to assign it to a new destination.

Comment: It's not correct that a trade route runs for the amount of turns displayed when initially starting one (the number at the arrow). That number only indicates how many turns your trader must use in order to reach the target city, nothing more.
The lowest amount of turns is somewhere around 15 (provided there are no more than 3 tiles between the cities) and the largest amount of turns is upwards 400 turns :).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot delete or cancel a trade unit. Your only hope would be to get someone to attack it or reload another save.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did but there was a specialized land improvement I could click on that would cause the trade route to cancel.  As long as I selected the trade unit first then clicked the improvement it would cancel the route.